# dconf Key Bind Is Visible But Doesn't Work

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, dconf, shortcut-keys

Since im a new ubuntu user, and am still using windows as my primary, I wanted to set the "Switch to next input source" keybind to Alt+Shift, but for some reason the settings dont allow that. So I looked around the internet and found it would be possible to use
dconf-editor for something like this, but when changing the key bind to `<Alt>shift` the change is visible in dconf but shows up as disabled in setting and doesn't work.
How do I make it work?
FYI im on ubuntu 20.04.05 LTS and am using gnome desktop.

[image: dconf-editor & settings]

Comment: It appears that the combination of Alt + Shift is not allowed for this shortcut. You need to enter a "real" key like <space> or <k>, not just a modifier key. It doesn't matter whether you do that on the Settings panel (right) or the dconf-editor (left).

Comment: @jos is there any other way to do it then?

Comment: I would choose another key combination if I were you.